# differential forms in double field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, differential-forms

In double field theory, there are 'double differential forms' meaning that the standard 1-forms $d x^i$ generate an algebra over functions depending on both of the double coordinates
$x^i$ and $\tilde x_i$.
Does $d \tilde x_i$ ever appear?